# Is it possible to get the page number and line number in iPhone

Tags: iphone, doc

Is it possible to get the page number and line number of particular text from doc/rtf/pdf in iPhone sdk?

Can QLPreviewController or UIDocumentInteractionController be of any help?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to create something like iAnnotate,Sente. Application where in user will be able to select some text and can add comments for selected text.

I have gone through the fastpdfkit api's which seems the only api which can be of some help.

Can you guys guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/brow/leaves

Go with this link, it will help you for PDF reader and you can see there how I am doing total page and current page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at doing this with PDF, RTF and DOC it might be best to approach it in a different way as they are all very different formats.

Instead - if you consider attaching comments to an area of the page as opposed to a specific text selection then all you need to know about the document is which page you're looking at. A much easier task. Then you get the user to 'drag out' a comments box for an area of that page. Think of them more like sticky-notes.

This way you can add comments to images as well as text and it allows a much more flexible system for support of other file formats in the future.

I realise this isn't I direct answer to the question, but thought it relevant enough to post.

Comment: yes ofcourse it is Wex. Thanks for your thought. I have already added it in my option list.

Comment: seems that nobody is able to answer the question. I will make sure that you get the bounty Wex if nobody answers it till eod.

Comment: Thanks. The actual answer is 'probably not'. The reason being that PDF files don't really have line-numbers. They have areas of text within the file-structure that can be all over the place (even backwards) - it's not internally structured in the order they appear on the screen.

Comment: hmm... den is there any way i can let user to select the text and make a mark somewhere that which text was selected.